# Не могу подключиться к PostgreSQL в докере при помощи команды psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

У меня не получается при помощи команды psql подключиться к postgres, запущенному в докере. Я запускаю постгрес при помощи docker compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Выполняю команду `docker-compose up -d`, все запускается. После этого я пытаюсь подключиться к докеру при помощи psql, чтобы загрузить базу данных из sql-файла: `psql -U postgres` или `psql -U postgres -f demo.sql` и полючаю ошибку:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432
> failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port
> 5432 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Почему происходит эта ошибка и как ее исправить? Порт постгреса торчит наружу из докера:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
d5742b7ca2ba   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   5432/tcp                                    postgres-db-1
b822f487eaf9   adminer    "entrypoint.sh php -…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   postgres-adminer-1
```

Comment: Вроде разобрался. Надо было замапить порт в секции ports